# How do I disable user input after the player made their choice?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to make a PvP minigame where both players have to chose 1 out of 3 options, but to avoid spamming I want to make it so that when a player presses a button, he is locked in that choice until the other player makes his choice too.

Comment: Show us your code and scene setup for handling the player's input. There are many many ways to skin this cat in Unity, and different methods of handling player input will entail different strategies for disabling it. So to suggest answers that will work in your case, we need to have enough details to reproduce your situation in a new project.

Comment: Have you tried using an `if` statement?